# How to change "Account Created In" value from the Customer grid in Admin panel

Tags: magento2.3, customer, admin-panel, customer-grid, account

The customer has a value of "Account Created In".[image]

They are also displayed in the customer grid.
[image]

If you change the value of "Send Welcome Email from" on the customer information edit screen,

[image]

The value of "Account Created In" will also change.
[image]

But the value of the customer grid does not change,
[image]

How do I change the values ​​in the customer grid as well?

Comment: try rebuilding the indexes `bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Just want to know, @Marius how re-indexing will help in this ?

Comment: it could. the customer grid data comes from an indexed table. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: I tried the command `bin/magento indexer:reindex` .
But it wasn't change.